# Legal definition of a "child" in the United States

Tags: criminal-law, legal-terms, massachusetts

I notice that in several criminal cases women who are clearly post-pubescent teenagers are being legally characterized as "children", so I am wondering about the terminology here. For example, in one case I read of man being prosecuted for "rape of a child", however the the alleged "child" was 16 years old: clearly past the age of puberty.

So, normally in the English language, a "child" is a pre-pubescent person--in other words someone not sexually capable of procreating, which would mean 13 years old at the latest. However, apparently in legal sphere and the press there is a tendency to describe teenagers who are clearly sexually capable as "children" and this is obviously being done to demonize those who commit sex crimes against teenagers and increase the severity of the crime.

I searched for the legal definition of a "child" under Massachusetts law and could not find any definition. So, is it just ambiguous what the word "child" means in Massachusetts? What about US Federal law. Is there a legal standard of what constitutes a "child"?

Comment: "this is obviously being done to demonize those who commit sex crimes against teenagers". Huh? Are you suggesting that every sexually mature child is actually an adult? That might be the case in some far-flung tribal societies, but some of those who have "adult initiation rites" still have a rule of law.

Comment: @WeatherVane "this is obviously being done to demonize those who commit sex crimes against teenagers". Cicero is not wrong about that. This is indeed one of the reasons that this terminology is used. Psychology, for example, recognizes the difference between a true pedophile who is attracted to prepubescent children, and someone who is far less deviant and attracted to younger post-pubescent children. Most statutory rape statutes likewise make the distinction, making intercourse with a younger child a more serious and easier to prove crime than with an older minor.

Comment: "normally in English...": Normally in most languages, including English, words have different senses. If a 15-year-old isn't a "child" because he or she has reached sexual maturity, what term would you use instead?  "Man" or "woman"?  I don't see many people using those words for people of that age.

Comment: @phoog "what term would you use instead" Historically, I believe the term used would have been "youth".

Comment: @nick012000 I've never seen that term used in a statute.  Have you?

Comment: "I searched for the legal definition of a "child" under Massachusetts law and could not find any definition": where did you look?  The Massachusetts criminal code has several different definitions for various offenses it defines.

Comment: @phoog I was talking in general terms about the historical use of the English language, not legal jargon specifically.

Comment: "Sex crimes against teenagers" - by definition, a teenager is someone from 13 years to 19 years old. I'm sure there are acts that are heinous crimes against some 13 year old teenagers and just normal against 19 year old teenagers.

Answer (score 7):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

The term "child" is expressly defined for various offences. For example, for [s. 172](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/c-46/section-172-20190919.html):

> child means a person who is or appears to be under the age of eighteen years.

The offence of "[child pornography](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/c-46/section-163.1.html)" is expressly defined to relate to "a person who is or is depicted as being under the age of eighteen years."

The offence of "[child luring](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-172.1-20150717.html#wb-cont)" has several variants, for luring those who are or who the accused believes to be under the age of 18, 16, or 14. They are all called "child luring."

Other sections criminalize conduct in relation to a child without defining the term. See e.g. [s. 243](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-243.html):

> Every person who in any manner disposes of the dead body of a child, with intent to conceal the fact that its mother has been delivered of it, whether the child died before, during or after birth, is guilty...

For s. 243, courts had to conduct statutory interpretation in order to determine the meaning of the word "child." The Supreme Court of Canada held that "child" in this offence includes children born alive and fetuses that were likely to have been born alive. See *R. v. Levkovic*, [2013 SCC 25](https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/scc-csc/en/item/13031/index.do).

I know this is Canadian law, rather than Massachusetts law, but one thing you can take away from this is that terms can take on distinct legal meanings from one provision to another. And where a term is not expressly defined in statute, its meaning will be enunciated by a court. These meanings need not line up with the definitions you find in a dictionary.

But, for a general description from a specialized dictionary, see *Black's Law Dictionary*, 10th ed. (2014):

> **child**. **1**. An unemancipated person under the age of majority. **2**. *Hist*. At common law, a person who has not reached the age of 14. **3**. A boy or girl; a young person. **4**. A son or daughter. **5**. A baby or fetus.

Comment: "one thing you can take away from this is that terms can take on distinct legal meanings from one provision to another." Absolutely. I've probably mentioned this 100 times at Law.SE. It is especially an issue in common law countries where there is less institutional support for generalized definitions than in civil law countries.

Comment: This. Exactly this. This isn't the end, either. There are some truly bizarre definitions used for common words in some statutes and titles of various jurisdictions. To understand what definition is used you have to read the statutes and case law.

Answer (score 4):

"Child" in the US typically means a minor, someone who is not yet 18.  Someone would be either a child or an adult.  Your belief in coded language for some reason is not part of this legal definition.

Child can also mean offspring, say in the use of wills.

If different definitions are used, they would be defined in the applicable law.

[Black's Legal dictionary](https://thelawdictionary.org/child/)

Comment: This is not really documented. In every English language dictionary it says a person between the ages of birth and puberty, so where is this redefinition of a "child" as a minor?

Comment: @Cicero The kind of criminal laws you are mentioning, where child is a measure of age rather than of a parent-child relationship (probate is full of cases about children who are in their 60s), child almost always means under the age of eighteen. Lots of legal terms use dated or non-plain language. For example, the legal word for a non-U.S. citizen in the United States is an "alien" and the phrase "Indian Country" is alive and well in U.S. law pertaining to Native Americans. Lots of employment law is part of the law datedly called the law of "Master and Servant".

Comment: @Cicero no, [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/child) says "... until he or she is an **adult**". It does not say 'puberty'.

Comment: @Cicero I added the Black's definition

Comment: @ohwilleke _alien_ refers to non-nationals of the US, not non-citizens.  Overlooking the existence of US non-citizen nationals has caused a few problems in immigration law over the years, notably a lack of statutory provision for them to sponsor foreign family members for immigration.  As far as I can tell the term "alien" has only become dated in the last 10 or 20 years, which I find profoundly weird.

Comment: @phoog "non-nationals of the US, not non-citizens" subtle but a fair point. A handful of recent court cases decline to use the term in court opinions explaining that they are doing so in footnotes.

Comment: The linked edition of Black's Law Dictionary is from 1910. The sense of the word as referring to someone under eighteen probably became predominant in the 1960s or 1970s.

Comment: The Black's Law Dictionary says "generally under the age of puberty" just as I said.

Comment: @phoog The word Alien comes from the Latin word "Alienus" which means "of or belonging to another".  The use of the word Alien to mean "Foreign person" dates back as far as 14th century and has been used as a legal term meaning as much in the U.S. since at least 1800.  The more modern use of "alien" meaning "extraterrestrial" dates back only as far as 1953, when UFO/Extraterrestrial phonomime became main stream.   To wit, the meaning is still preserved in that use, as Martians are definitely foreign to the United States.

Comment: @Cicero A statutory definition (which is almost certainly present in a criminal offense) would control over any dictionary definition and the meaning of the word has evolved since 1910.

Comment: @hszmv I've known all of those facts for decades.  What is your point in calling them to my attention?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of Massachusetts (Mass.) the definition of "child" means different things depending on the laws in question.   Generally, a "child" for the purposes of the legal age of criminal prosecution is defined as any child younger than 12 years old at the time of the crime (Mass. has the highest age of criminal prosecution in the United States.)  Federally, this age is any child younger than 11 years of age.

In terms of Age of Consent (the legal age in which a person may give consent to a sexual relationship) is 16 years and over.  Federally, this is 18 years or older.

Legally speaking, 18 is the age at which a person is considered a legal adult (although I know few 18 year olds who have adult sensibilities... but I also know a few 60+ year olds who have no adult sensibilities... you're only young once but you can be immature forever as they say.).   This means that you can legally vote, smoke, screw (if you're one of the prudish states that has 18 as the age of legal consent... like California.), and die for your nation (but you can't drown your sorrows until you're 21.).   Additionally, unless you are legally emancipated, your rights can be restricted by a legal guardian (parents or other parental substitute).

All people above the age of criminal liability but below the age of legal adulthood are also handled through a juvenile court system in the U.S. (I don't think this applies to federal courts as they don't have one, but they so rarely prosecute crimes compared to the state... let alone juvie crimes) although judges may grant exception for legal juviniles to be tried in adult court if the crime is serious enough (or they're close to legal adulthood either).  Juvie Courts are less open than adult court and any juvenile record is sealed after the offender turns 18 (meaning that if you were a 13-year-old busted for taking the neighbor's car on a joy ride, it won't follow you to adulthood in the legal system.  The public memory will not always forget).

In your particular scenario, one of a few things could have happened.  Either she was 16 at the time of the rape and did not consent, OR she was 15 at the time of the rape (which even if she did give consent, it doesn't matter as the law says she's not able to give it no matter what.) and has since had a 16th birthday while the trial makes its way through the courts.  Another possibility is that the relationship involved someone who was traveling from out of state OR she traveled out of state to meet him, which makes this a crime that could involve the Federal Government, in which case, she is not yet 18 and thus it was a statutory rape (even if she was consenting to the encounter).

Finally, the article or speaker who called her a child might not be using a legal sense of the word, but a more colloquial sense, in which case, the range is considerably broader (As a general rule, among the uninformed, child has a broad range.  While she is a teenager, she is still young enough that she would be living with her parents and not yet ready to "leave the nest" as an adult would.  Biologically speaking, humans have a long adolescent period compared to most animals, with a biological maturity taking as long as 25 years by some estimates.) and it's not uncommon for our language to reflect that.  As such, the claim might not be one of legal childhood, but a frame of reference to remind adults that she's still got a lot of growing up to do and the accused rapist ignored that when he had sex with her.  Remember, he's going to be judged by a jury of his peers... the prosecution wants them to use there vernacular understanding of her age, not their legal understanding.

Answer (score 2):

> I searched for the legal definition of a "child" under Massachusetts
> law and could not find any definition.

The definitions are right there in the criminal statutes. The relevant MA statutes are quite clear and different ages apply to different offenses. *See, e.g.*, the following:

> § 22A. Rape of child; punishment
>
> Whoever has sexual intercourse or unnatural sexual intercourse with a
> child under 16, and compels such child to submit by force and against
> his will or compels such child to submit by threat of bodily injury,
> shall be punished by imprisonment in the state prison for life or for
> any term of years. . . .

Mass. Gen. Laws Ann. ch. 265, § 22A.

> § 22B. Rape of a child during commission of certain offenses or by use
> of force; penalties
>
> Whoever has sexual intercourse or unnatural sexual intercourse with a
> child under 16, and compels such child to submit by force and against
> his will or compels such child to submit by threat of bodily injury
> and: . . .

Mass. Gen. Laws Ann. ch. 265, § 22B.

> § 22C. Rape of a child through use of force by certain previously
> convicted offenders; penalties
>
> Whoever has sexual intercourse or unnatural sexual intercourse with a
> child under 16, and compels such child to submit by force and against
> his will or compels such child to submit by threat of bodily injury,
> and has been previously convicted of or adjudicated delinquent or as a
> youthful offender for: indecent assault and battery on a child under
> 14 as set forth in section 13B; aggravated indecent assault and
> battery on a child under 14 as set forth in section 13B ½; indecent
> assault and battery on a person 14 or older as set forth in section
> 13H; assault of a child with intent to commit rape as set forth in
> section 24B; rape of a child with force as set forth in section 22A;
> aggravated rape of a child with force as set forth in section 22B;
> rape and abuse of a child as set forth in section 23; aggravated rape
> and abuse of a child as set forth in section 23A; rape as set forth in
> section 22; or a like violation of the laws of another state, the
> United States or a military, territorial or Indian tribal authority,
> shall be punished by imprisonment in the state prison for life or for
> any term of years, but not less than 20 years. . . .

Mass. Gen. Laws Ann. ch. 265, § 22C.

*See generally* [Mass. Gen. Laws Ann. ch. 265,](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartIV/TitleI/Chapter265) §§ 13b to 27a.

Comment: Side question: I find the repeated phrase "sexual intercourse or unnatural sexual intercourse" confusing. How is the latter not by definition a subset of the former? One wouldn't say "You are not allowed to drive faster than x mph with a vehicle or purple vehicle" either

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The terms are defined in the statute. Basically, sexual intercourse means vaginal sex between opposite sex people, and unnatural sexual intercourse means any other kind of physically touching sexual activity involving more than one person, although one would need to look at the precise definitions to get it perfectly correct.